# URL Hack question

Tags: custom-field, page-layout, urlhacking

I have a custom object called Milestone, which is attached as a junction object to a custom object called Invoice and Opportunities. I'm trying to build a button on Opportunity page layout with a URL hack behind it to build and save

I'd like to populate the object's Opportunity Lookup field, but for some reason the URL isn't working. Here's the URL:

/a02/e?%2F006%2Fo&RecordType=012j0000000LDXn&Name={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Nj000000By4QB_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}

The Milestone Name populates using the Opportunity name just fine, but the lookup field doesn't populate with the Opportunity ID.

If anyone has any thoughts, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Field ID is `CF00Nj000000By4QB`

The URL would be:

```
/a02/e?%2F006%2Fo&RecordType=012j0000000LDXn&CF00Nj000000By4QB=
{!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Nj000000By4QB_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
```

> - CF00Nj000000By4QB = display text
> - CF00Nj000000By4QB_lkid = id

Comment: In this case "Name" in the original URL is Milestone name field, not Opportunity name, but I think if I change this to

/a02/e?%2F006%2Fo&RecordType=012j0000000LDXn&Name={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Nj000000By4QB={!Opportunity.Name}

Correct?

Comment: Just tried, that looks like it worked!